# Pulse generator ll - Art of Electronics

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, bjt, pulse, signal-generator

[image]

How does Q3 hold Q1 at ground? I understand the operation of the pulse generator, I just don't get how q3 holds the collector of q1 at ground.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Comment: This is what I am going to try next with circuit lab. Still, I am not sure if I will get any intrinsic info about why this happens? The purpose of q3 is to hold q1 at ground once the pulse begins so that the duration of the input pulse doesn't interfere with the operation of C1 and q2. But I just don't get why the transistor q3 does that. Pulse generator lll with an upgrade uses a Schmitt trigger which acts pretty much the same. A transistor holds its output the at ground once it gets activated. I just don't get why this happens.

Comment: Try it in your simulator and test scenarios as what if Q3 does not hold down Q1.

Comment: Is this a terminology issue? Perhaps it’s clearer to say that “Q3 keeps the collector of Q1 at a low potential when the output pulse is active”?

Comment: Imagine Q3 were replaced by a relay. Would it then be easier to understand?

Comment: @Finbarr-kinda. Plus, thinking that it pretty much does the same thing (acting as a switch amongst others) it does help. But it isn't really the same , is it :)

Comment: @Bryan I understand what happens. The emf potential falls to ground (at least near it). I only wonder why that happens. A transistor after all does pull its own collector near ground when it is saturated. Perhaps this is the reason. But I am not fully convinced. Anyway I'll run a simulation when I am able to access my computer.

Comment: Q2 and Q3 is a very common monostable circuit. Q1 just triggers it with short pulse to Q1 base. Btw, you can avoid Q1 by triggering to Q3 base using diode only.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický "Monostable multivibrator, in which one of the states is stable, but the other state is unstable (transient). A trigger pulse causes the circuit to enter the unstable state. After entering the unstable state, the circuit will return to the stable state after a set time."- This also makes sense why the output is a square wave in the first place. The rise of the wave is the equivalent of the trigger and the descending slope is the stabilisation of the wave to ground. It is some sort of logical circuit? The values of Q1 and Q3 jump from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0. Cool stuff. Thanks

Comment: @DavidAb Do you have an answer you can accept already? Or is there something else? I've got the 3rd edition of AofE sitting in front of me and looking at pages 77 and 78. They explain exactly what they are trying to achieve and I can write something in the context of what they are saying. But you may already have all you need. Just checking.

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks, that's very thoughtful, but I don't have a problem with this circuit anymore (I also searched for past explanations in this site and they were enough to give me the basic idea). Then I have put the idea on a breadboard to test some things regarding the circuit and it clarified everything  completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the pulse at the input will turn ON the Q1 into saturation.
Thus, the previously charged capacitor (C1) will pull down the Q2 base below GND (around -4.3V). So, Q2 will be cut off. And C1 will start the "discharge process" via R3.
[image]

Now, since Q2 is cut off there is a path from Vcc via R4 and R5 resistors to turn ON the Q3. Thus, Q3 will turn ON and it will enter the saturation region.
So now, even when the input pulse ends Q2 will remain cut off because now the Q3 collector will "pull down" the C1 left plate to the ground.
Thus the capacitor will continue to charge towards Q2 vbe voltage.

[image]

And when C1 voltage finally reaches 0.6V the Q2 will start to conduct current.
This will cut off Q3 and the capacitor will be instantly recharged to around 4.3V.

[image]
We have reached a steady state and we are ready to "receive" the next impulse at the input.

Comment: It makes sense. In the book it talked about how it pulls Q1 to ground when in fact it only pulls C1 to ground and let's Q1 do whatever it wants. I have also seen some circuits which in fact do pull the collector of a transistor to ground via another transistor. I discovered that it is some kind of monostable multivibrator with te help of someone. Thanks.

Comment: Does this analysis assume Vbe = 0.7V and Vce (saturation) = 0V? I'm trying to figure out the operation of the circuit myself but I can't get the -4.3V and +4.8V figures you did.

Comment: @daviegravee Yes, I heved assumed that the Vbe = 0.7V and Vce(sat) = 0V.  Do you have any additional questions about the circuit?

Comment: @G36 Yes, how did you get -4.3V on the base of Q2? And 4.8V at the output? I calculated the output voltage with Q2 cut off as (5v -0.7v)/21kOhm * 20kOhm = 4.095V

Comment: @daviegravee 4.3V is the voltage across the C1 plates. To this voltage, C1 will be charged when Q1 and Q2 are off.  The "positive" will be on the "left side" (left C1 plate). Thus, when Q1 is saturated and pulls down the collector to GND we literally connect C1 left plate to GND (the positive side of a capacitor plate). This means that the right plate will be at -4.3V below GND. Do you see it now? As for the output voltage. What you did is calculate the voltage drop across the 20kOhms resistor. Not the voltage at the output.

Comment: @G36 Yep, silly mistake of mine with the output voltage. I think i've understood your explanation of of how -4.3V is measured at the base of Q2. To rephrase what you said in my own words (to confirm my understanding): When Q1 initially "closes" (is in saturation), the plate of the capacitor that was charged to 4.3V gets connected to ground. The capacitor cannot discharge instantaneously, so there moment it is connected to ground there is still a 4.3V differential across the plates, and one plate is tied to 0V, meaning the right-plate must be -4.3V.

Comment: @daviegravee Your, -4.3V explanation looks good to me.  As for the output voltage:   \$V_O = V_{CC} - I_BR_4\$